# Auto Convert Classic asp to Asp.net 2 or MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I would like to know if there any tools that can run in a win 7 64 bit machine to convert my classic asp site to Web Form/MVC in C#.  I found there was a tool to convert it in Framework 1.1, but it doesn't work quite well.

Can someone suggest?

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything that will do this. I know there was a tool to help with classic asp -> .net 1.1 as you mention, but that's very old and likely also out of date. This is probably a by-hand job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, such tool doesn't exist and even if it existed, I doubt that it would convert anything accurately. ASP.NET and ASP are different paradigms.

You need to do this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents and not an answer per-se, is to not try and update the entire website at once. Particularly if it is large site. It is quite trivial to run classic and asp.net websites side by side. Make new pages/functionality asp.net. As you are doing that break the website down into functional units then start to convert those units.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer but in my opinion it would be less painful going from asp classic directly to mvc, they are somehow closer in their approach to web development, webforms use a complete different paradigm that relies on an artificial event model. Having said that I don't know about any conversion tool that can help you in the process, and as you already found out, the conversion tool on framework 1.1 doesn't really work.